# Trying to handle thread pool in a class

Tags: multithreading, winapi, visual-c++

I'm trying to handle thread pool in a class.
below is my code.

```
#include <Windows.h>

class ClassA
{
public : // user API
    ClassA()
    {
    }

    ~ClassA()
    {
    }

public : //my muiti-thread func

    void init()
    {
        //*************************************
        // multithread Initialization
        //*************************************
        pool = NULL;
        cleanupgroup = NULL;
        rollback = 0;
        bool bRet = false;

        pool = CreateThreadpool(NULL);
        if(NULL == pool)
        {
            goto cleanPool;
        }
        rollback = 1;                                       

        SetThreadpoolThreadMaximum(pool, 5);                
        bRet = SetThreadpoolThreadMinimum(pool, 10);

        if (FALSE == bRet) {
            goto cleanPool;
        }

        cleanupgroup = CreateThreadpoolCleanupGroup();

        if (NULL == cleanupgroup) {
            goto cleanPool; 
        }

        rollback = 2;                                       

        SetThreadpoolCallbackPool(&CallBackEnviron, pool);

        SetThreadpoolCallbackCleanupGroup(&CallBackEnviron,
            cleanupgroup,
            NULL);

        return ;

cleanPool:
        switch (rollback) 
        {
        case 2:
            // Clean up the cleanup group.
            CloseThreadpoolCleanupGroup(cleanupgroup);

        case 1:
            // Clean up the pool.
            CloseThreadpool(pool);

        default:
            break;
        }

        return ;
    }

    void foo()
    {
        PTP_WORK work = NULL;
        work = CreateThreadpoolWork(ClassA::_delegate,
                        NULL, 
                        &CallBackEnviron);
    }

    static void __stdcall _delegate(PTP_CALLBACK_INSTANCE Instance, PVOID Parameter, PTP_WORK Work)
    {
        //some code
    }

    PTP_POOL pool;
    UINT rollback;
    TP_CALLBACK_ENVIRON CallBackEnviron;    
    PTP_CLEANUP_GROUP cleanupgroup;
};

int main()
{
    ClassA a;
    a.init();
    a.foo();
}
```

If you make a project and execute this code, it gets unhandled execption...
I have no clue why...

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but you might find the Boost.Thread library easier to use and more portable.

Comment: @crowder does boost can handle pool in the class??

Comment: There are lots of examples of thread pools on this site.

Comment: I have googled and searched to find similar case as me to handle thread pool in a class but had no result. Will you help me if there is any examples of it?

Comment: http://threadpool.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Did you try a debugger? Where is the exception occurring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the exception is caused by an uninitialized structure CallBackEnviron. The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682478.aspx) states that this structure must be initialized by [InitializeThreadpoolEnvironment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683486.aspx)

Comment: Adding InitializeThreadpoolEnvironment( &CallBackEnviron ) in init(), just before SetThreadpoolCallbackPool make the exception vanish.